# Fourier coefficients of smooth functions behave like Schwartz functions?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, smooth-functions, schwartz-space

Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a $1$-periodic $L^1([0,1])$ function. Hence, the Fourier coefficients
$$a_n = \int_0^1 f(x)\exp(-2\pi i nx) dx$$
are well definied. Do we now have the equivalence
$$f \in C^\infty(\mathbb R)
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
\forall k \in \mathbb N \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n n^k = 0?
$$
I think I proved the direction "$\Leftarrow$" (if I'm not mistaken, please correct me otherwise), so I'm only left with "$\Rightarrow$". Is this true as well?

Comment: I just saw: It seems like the questions can be answered with yes by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Magnitude_of_Fourier_coefficients Do you have a proof for me?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, integration by parts (take $u = f(x)$, $v' = e^{-2 \pi i n x}$) reveals
\begin{align}
\widehat{f}(n)
& = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) e^{-2 \pi i n x} \; \text{d}x
= f(x) \frac{e^{-2 \pi i n x}}{- 2 \pi i n}\bigg|_{x = 0}^{1}
+ \frac{1}{2 \pi i n} \int_{0}^{1} f(x) e^{-2 \pi i n x} \; \text{d}x \\
& = \frac{1}{2 \pi i n} \int_{0}^{1} f'(x) e^{-2 \pi i n x} \; \text{d}x
= \frac{1}{2 \pi i n} \widehat{f'}(n),
\end{align}
for any $n \in \mathbb Z$, where in the second to last equality we used that $f$ is 1-periodic.
One can now proceed inductively to obtain that
$$
\widehat{f}(n)
= \frac{1}{(2 \pi i n)^k} \widehat{f^{(k)}}(n)
$$
Hence if $f \in \mathcal{C}^{k}(\mathbb{R})$, then
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} n^k \hat{f}(n)
= \lim_{n \to \infty} n^k \frac{1}{(2 \pi i n)^{k}}\widehat{f^{(k)}}(n)
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{(2 \pi i)^{k}}\widehat{f^{(k)}}(n)
= 0,
$$
as $\widehat{} \colon L^1 \to \mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R})$, that is, the Fourier transformed function is a continuous function vanishing at the boundary.

Comment: But what is the $L^1$ function to start with? The function $f$ is not in $L^1(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain But it says that $f \in L^1$ in the first sentence of post. If $f \not \in L^1$, then the Fourier coefficients must not exist, so this needs to be assumed for the statement you want to prove to make sense.

Comment: If $f$ is periodic and $L^1(\mathbb R)$ at the same time $f$ has to vanish almost everywhere.

Comment: when I write $L^1$ I mean $L^1([0, 1])$.

Comment: Now I think there might be a gap to close in my solution for the other direction. If I have this fast decay of the Fourier coefficients I get that the Fourier series converges to a smooth function. But why is this smooth function almost everywhere identical with $f$? If $f$ would be in addition in $L^2([0,1])$ this would be clear because in $L^2([0,1])$ it is an isomorphism of Hilbert spaces to map a function to its Fourier coefficients (as element of $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$). But in $L^1$ I don't know.

Comment: There is also another problem with your solution: If you want $\hat f$ to be the Fourier transform then you don't have $\hat f(n)=a_n$ because for $\hat f(n)$ you integrate over $\mathbb R$ and for $a_n$ over $[0,1]$.

Comment: I don't agree. As $f$ is one-periodic, the definition of the Fourier coefficients in this integral over $[0, 1]$.