# Periodic sum smooth iff it comes from Schwartz function?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, schwartz-space

Let's start with a continuous function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with enough decay to make
$$F(x) := \sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} f(x+k)$$
converge absolutely and uniformly (side question: does in this case absolute convergence imply uniform convergence?).
Then $F$ is a $1$-periodic continuous function and we are allowed to change the summation with integration in the process of finding the Fourier coefficients of $F$ and it turns out
$$a_n := \int_0^1 F(x)\exp(-2\pi i nx) dx = \hat f(n)$$
where
$$\hat f(y) := \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \exp(-2 \pi i xy) dx$$
is the Fourier transform of $f$.

Now in [Fourier coefficients of smooth functions behave like Schwartz functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4314992/fourier-coefficients-of-smooth-functions-behave-like-schwartz-functions) I learnt that the smoothness of $F$ is equivalent to having a faster than any polynomial decay of the $a_n$. Does this give us the following equivalence
$$ F \in C^\infty \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad f \in S(\mathbb R)$$
since the Fourier transform is an automorphism on $\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$? With $S(\mathbb R)$ I mean the Schwartz space of functions $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: No. Say $\hat f=\chi_{(1/3,2/3)}$. Then $F=0$ (because $\hat f(n)=0$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$) but $f\notin S$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich If this really is a counter-example you have to say  what $f$ is. Is it continuous?

Comment: Saying $\hat f=\chi_{(1/3,2/3}$ says what $f$ is! Its the inverse Fourier transform of $\chi_{(1/3,2/3)}$. Yes, it's continuous, being the transform of an $L^1$ function...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Marvelous counterexample!